# Why can't I see Node and Yarn in my global node modules list?

Tags: node.js, npm, package, yarnpkg, package-managers

I was reading [this documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm) on how to upgrade my version of `npm` and it mentioned I needed a particular version of Node. I looked at my list of global node modules using `npm ls -g --depth 0` (or equivalently `ls /usr/local/lib/node_modules`) and noticed that that list contains `npm`, but not Node or Yarn. I know that I have Node and Yarn installed because `node -v` and `yarn -v` both return version numbers, so I'm wondering why they aren't in my list of global modules.

Comment: Did you install Yarn and Node using `npm install -g`?

Comment: I don't remember for sure. But what I just noticed is that yarn and node are in /usr/local/bin. `npm ls -g --depth 0` pointed me to /usr/local/lib/node_modules. I know that executables get installed in /usr/local/bin and libraries in /usr/local/lib, but do you know why node and yarn would be installed in /usr/local/bin only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most probably you didn't use `npm` to install node or yarn, rather they must be binaries.

Use `which` command to find out the location of these binaries. This is how it looks on my system:

```
which yarn
/usr/local/bin/yarn
```

and

```
which node
/Users/user/.nvm/versions/node/v8.11.2/bin/node
```

Comment: I think you're right, for `which yarn` and `which node` I get "/usr/local/bin/yarn" and "usr/local/bin/node", respectively. Do you know why my location for node might be different from yours?

Comment: Also, separate question, but do you use any strategy to keep all your modules up to date without manually checking each one against the latest version?

Comment: 1. my node directory is different because I use [nvm](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm) to manage multiple node versions on my system.
2. On running `npm install`, packge-lock.json automatically updates to the latest versions of packages according to the package.json. Also, you can use `npm outdated` to find out new versions published on registry.
Hope it helps!

Comment: Ok thanks, Re "npm install" though, is there a way to keep track of which GLOBAL packages are out of date? I've approved your answer either way :)

Comment: [npm docs](http://npm.github.io/using-pkgs-docs/working-with-packages/updating-global-packages.html) suggest you can use `npm outdated -g --depth=0` for this purpose. Thanks for the accepted answer.